# Best practive firestore listener: multple per path, or one doing multple jobs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

What would be the best Firestore way to use Firestore Function on database changes?

When we have a change in a path/{answer_id} we do 3 things:

- update /path/1
- do a calculation function
- update /path/3

These items can be done independent from each other.
When we have multiple, maybe longer running jobs, is it best to write 3 listeners each doing their own thing, or have one listener calling 3 functions?

Comment: The question asks about 'listeners' but the three tasks you perform have nothing to do with listening. In other words, updating a document because of a change in a different document doesn't require a listener.  For example suppose the app is listening for changes in a /users collection. User_A changes his favorite food selection and your app is notified. Your app then changes 25 other notes that reference that user. Those 25 nodes do not require a listener to be updated. If that's not what you're asking, can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as follows:

1. You want to have a Cloud Function that is triggered when a document in the `path` collection is updated ("When we have a change in a path/{answer_id} ").
2. This Cloud Function shall do three "**actions**": update two (other) documents in the same `path` collection and also do a calculation
3. These three actions are totally decoupled and can be done independently (in particular, no need to write to the two documents in an atomic way)

If those assumptions are correct:

- You could very well implement three Cloud Functions, each one doing one of the three actions. This will cost three Cloud Function invocations.
- On the other hand, you could very well implement these three actions in a unique Cloud Function. You just need to take care to terminate the Cloud Function when all the [asynchronous work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). This will cost only one Cloud Function invocation.
- About the "longer running jobs", the only long running job I can see is the calculation, since writing to a Firestore document is usually a "short running job". So if you see a risk that you reach the 9 minutes timeout, it will probably be caused by the long calculation, not by the updates to the two Firestore documents => so, IMHO there is no difference here between one CF and three CFs.
- One reason I can see that would justify separating in three Cloud Functions would be to have different strategies in terms of [function retrying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries).

In conclusion, based on your input (which doesn't provide a lot of details), I don't see any advantage of using three different Cloud Functions.